# Get UL attribute clicking on a LI item

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with jquery :)

I want, after clicking on a `li` item, to get the `question` attribute of the `ul` where the `li` is contained.

I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ez88dcn8/

Jquery Markup:

```
$(document).on('click','.js_test', function() {
    var selectedTool = $(this).attr("tool");
    var selectedType = $(this).attr("type");
    alert("selectedTool-> " + selectedTool + " selectedType-> " + selectedType);
});
```

how can i get the attribute i want of `ul` ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to your question.

Comment: `$(this).closest("ul").whatever` - you didn't try very hard, did you...?

Comment: Please note that you are putting your click event handler on the anchors, not on the list items.

Comment: Updated my answer to shine some light on the problems of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.closest()` method to get the question attr in the UL

```
 $(document).on('click','.js_test, li', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).closest('ul').attr('question'));
  });
```

or another way use .parent() method in jquery

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr('question')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ez88dcn8/5/

Comment: It returns undefined if you click the li rather than the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedQuestion = $(this).closest("ul").attr("question");
```

jQuery documentation for `.closest()`:

> https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Please note that you are using **invalid HTML attributes**. You can make them valid by prefixing their names with `data-`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ez88dcn8/3/

Please also note that you are putting your click event handler on the *anchors*, not on the *list items*. This is why clicking on the `li` rather than on the `a.js_test` returns `undefined` (because the `li` does not have the attributes you want to read).

You can fix this by either putting the click handler on the list items instead of the anchors (and then adjust the selectors for the attributes accordingly `var selectedType = $(this).find('a.js_test').attr("type");`) or by making the anchors `display: block;` so they grab the full  `li` space (which is what I did in the fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You need to find the `parent` using `closest()` and get the `question` attribute as follows,

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.js_test', function() {

      var selectedTool = $(this).attr("tool");
      var selectedType = $(this).attr("type");


      alert($(this).closest('ul').attr("question"));


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 tools-5" style="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="dropdown open">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Test 222</button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" question="5">

        <li><a class="js_test" value="shortlink" tool="ss" type="0">ita</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="js_test" value="shortlink" tool="ss" type="3">ger</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest`, `parent` and `parents` methods. Personally I prefer to use `parent` and `parents` depending on the case.

try with:

**All `<ul>` parents:**

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    var ul = $(this).parents('ul');
    console.log(ul.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click element</h3>
<ul id="all">
  <li>
    English
    <ul id="english">
      <li>Hi</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Español
    <ul id="spanish">
      <li>Hola</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**First `<ul>` parent:**

```js
$('ul li ul li').on('click', function() {
    var ul = $(this).parent('ul');
    console.log(ul.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click sub-element</h3>

<ul id="all">
    <li>
      English
      <ul id="english">
        <li>Hi</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Español
    <ul id="spanish">
      <li>Hola</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And if you want get some attribute, you can use `data` or `attr` like:

```js
$('ul li ul li').on('click', function() {
    var ul = $(this).parent('ul');
    console.log('Attribute data-question:', ul.data('question'));
    console.log('Attribute question:', ul.attr('question'));
    console.log('Attribute id:', ul.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click sub-element</h3>

    <ul id="all">
        <li>
          English
          <ul id="english" data-question="1" question="2">
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Español
        <ul id="spanish" data-question="3" question="4">
          <li>Hola</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Learn more here:

- [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [closests()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)